# Custom Node server causes Nextjs to fail to load 'No `pages` directory found'

Tags: https, next.js

I'm trying to bootstrap a new Nextjs app, and for integrating with Auth0 I need my localhost to be running HTTPS. I followed the guide here (https://medium.com/responsetap-engineering/nextjs-https-for-a-local-dev-server-98bb441eabd7), and generated a local certificate which is in more trusted certificate store.

To use HTTPS for localhost, you apparently need to create a custom server (this seems an odd oversight on the Nextjs side), so here's my custom server:

```
const { createServer } = require('https');
const { parse } = require('url');
const next = require('next');
const fs = require('fs');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev, dir: __dirname });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./certificates/ReactDevCertificate.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./certificates/ReactDevCertificate.cer'),
};

app.prepare().then(() => {
    createServer(httpsOptions, (req, res) => {
        const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
        handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
    }).listen(3000, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('> Server started on https://localhost:3000');
    });
});
```

Now, previous without the custom server, the app loads fine. But, with the custom server, it fails to load:

```
➜ yarn run dev
yarn run v1.22.15
$ next dev ./server.js
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
Error: > No `pages` directory found. Did you mean to run `next` in the parent (`../`) directory?
    at Object.findPagesDir (C:\Clients\ING\Framework\samples\fictionist-ui\node_modules\next\dist\lib\find-pages-dir.js:31:15)
    at new DevServer (C:\Clients\ING\Framework\samples\fictionist-ui\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:110:44)
    at NextServer.createServer (C:\Clients\ING\Framework\samples\fictionist-ui\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:102:20)
    at C:\Clients\ING\Framework\samples\fictionist-ui\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:117:42
    at async NextServer.prepare (C:\Clients\ING\Framework\samples\fictionist-ui\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:92:24)
    at async C:\Clients\ING\Framework\samples\fictionist-ui\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js:126:9
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

It feels like *somewhere* the app has navigated to a child folder, as there is code in the function `find-pages-dir.js` (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/lib/find-pages-dir.ts#L22) that looks specifically to the parent directory for the `pages` folder.

For reference, here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "fictionist-ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev ./server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "12.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "16.11.6",
    "@types/react": "17.0.33",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.1",
    "typescript": "4.4.4"
  }
}
```

OS: Windows 11
NPM: 16.9.0
Yarn: 1.22.15

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was that I didn't get the command right:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "node server.js" // was "next dev ./server.js"
}
```